# SharePoint: Step by Step guide to creating a list and list instance

Tags: sharepoint

I found an excellent tutorial on how to create site columns and content types - here : http://www.vimeo.com/5665655 (THANKS AGAIN ROB!)

Does anyone know of a written or video tutorial that will explain how to create a list and list instance in MOSS 2007.

I use WSP Builder, and the build in templates from Microsoft aren't compatible (or up to the task).

Preferably a method that focuses on the CAML (xml) , and explains in detail the theory, and demonstrates how it is done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inside Microsoft® Windows® SharePoint® Services 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/MSPress/books/9692.aspx) is a good book for this topic.  Refer  to **Chapter 6: Lists and Content Types**

Also Refer to the Andrew [post](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/02/08/A-Quicker-Way-to-Create-Custom-SharePoint-List-Templates.aspx) on the Subject it has other links as well

Comment: Thanks Kusek for your answer, sadly this is the best answer there is - SharePoint is a nightmare.

Comment: JL go ahead with the above two links, if you come across any issues in the mean time I would love to help you. Because I do this List Instance and List Template as a Regular Job.

Comment: Well your answer worked out very nicely, I followed Andrew's post down to the last letter. Open heart surgery might arguably be easier than working with MOSS, but at least phase 1 is complete now :)

Comment: JL MOSS is like riding the cycle, once you get hold the art of balancing you will enjoy the ride. But it will be tough to get it initially.